# ExpressJS serving html, android, iOS

Tags: android, ios, node.js, express, socket.io

I currently have a real-time web app built on the express framework with socket.io. Now, I may have coded myself into a hole here. I need to expand the app to handle requests from mobile devices (android first and then iOS in the future). I am having a hard time finding appropriate guides/examples for the following concerns:

1. Route separation for web browser/android/iOS
2. Sending and receiving JSON on an android device
3. Dynamic layouts based on JSON

I have many questions but hopefully someone has some reading material I can go through before asking aimless questions.

Much appreciated.

Comment: If you already have a web app you only need to add appropriate interfaces and use them. I always suggest an approach in which APIs are separated from GUI and so every device/web page can access to them

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are saying that my API need not change. I need to write it in a way it can serve whatever media connects to it. So, for example, I create and android app that connects to the server. I should add in route handing to serve this medium appropriately( ie JSON instead of HTML)?

Comment: For this you can use the Accept HTTP header, if it is application/json then serve it and so on...